# browse button not function well

Tags: jquery, html

This is code Java Script: looping value from database..

```
 i=1;

 $('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"]').find('input[data-type="btnBrowse"]').attr('data-type', i);
 $('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"]').find('div[data-type="UploadSignature"]').attr('data-type', i);

    $('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"] div[data-type="'+ i + '"]').on('click', function (event) {
    $('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"] input[type="file"][data-type="Document"]').click();

           //Start preview upload file module
           $('#loadFile').change(function (event) {
           var output = document.getElementById('output');
           output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            });
             //end preview upload file module
   });
...
i++;

<input type="button" data-type="btnBrowse" value="Browse" style="width:75px" />
```

I have a question why I clicked the button browser file but getting 4 times appear select file. suppose 1 time only.. May be I have 4 records right now.

getting this error: https://gyazo.com/dec211a613254aa6ec3bc18dea72dae9

Comment: Improve your question. Didn't get what you are trying to say

Comment: How find the button in correct way??

Comment: This is last I get ID for this button browse https://gyazo.com/287b1eaa2a2763d3614cdba53bce39ed

Comment: where is the ID of the button in that ?

Comment: actually this is the accordion list.. I have 4 records right now.. so I want click the browser button for upload file. but prompt out 4 times.